When creating a shortcut, how do I open Photos and make a local library the target?
I'm trying to create a shortcut on my iMac that will find all videos shorter than 3 seconds in a local library (that consists solely of videos).  I have tried option+opening Photos and selecting the desired target library and then running my shortcut, but the shortcut still searches the default library and adds a folder to that library. So I presume I must specify the target library in the shortcut.
